# Is there a proper way of creating a c/c++ struct using the dbus systemd/sd-bus API?

Tags: c, dbus

I have been working with dbus recently, more specifically with the sd-bus API.
Until now I have only used basic data types to pass as input to method calls, or to receive from signals/properties.

But now I would really like to know if it is possible to create a simple sender program in c, which only has a vtable with a readable property, ideally this property should contain all the attributes of a predefined struct. And then read the struct values in a reader program in c.

I have been trying some solutions I found researching internet, as well as by using the help of chatGPT, but no matter what I came up with I always ended up with a segmentation fault when I reach the message read function. Plus I don't quite understand the usage of the `getter function` chatGPT is recommending me which is linked to the property itself in the sender.

I'm providing both the sender.c file and the reader.c file c, I tried the approach of parsing the bus message directly to a `const char *pointer`, as well as the `size_t size`. And the `memcpy` the result to a local instance of a struct in the reader, handling issues regarding possible differences in size, but still couldn't avoid the segmentation fault. I tried to cast the result of the message read directly to an empty local instance of the struct, but the result was still a segmentation fault.

I'm wondering if what I'm trying to achieve is possible and makes sense, or if I should directly provide an array of basic data types as the properties directly, instead of trying to pass the struct.

Thank you so much beforehand for taking the time to read my question, any pointers would be appreciated.

Source code for the sender.c:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <systemd/sd-bus.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct Example {
    int a;
    const char *b;
    bool c;
} Example;

// I think this function creates an array out of the data of the struct and appends it to the
// sd_bus_message, not quite sure
static int example_get_property(sd_bus *bus, const char *path,
                                const char *interface, const char *property,
                                sd_bus_message *reply, void *userdata,
                                sd_bus_error *error) {
    Example *ex = (Example *)userdata;
    sd_bus_message_append_array(reply, 'y', ex, sizeof(Example));
    return 1;
}

static const sd_bus_vtable example_vtable[] = {
    SD_BUS_VTABLE_START(0),
    SD_BUS_PROPERTY("Example_property", "ay", example_get_property, 0,
                    SD_BUS_VTABLE_PROPERTY_EMITS_CHANGE),
    SD_BUS_VTABLE_END};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    sd_bus_slot *slot = NULL;
    sd_bus_error error = SD_BUS_ERROR_NULL;
    sd_bus *bus = NULL;
    sd_bus_message *message = NULL;
    Example example = {.a = 69, .b = "random test", .c = false};
    int r = sd_bus_open(&bus);
    if (r < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open system bus, error code %s\n",
                strerror(-r));
        printf("Exiting program\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    r = sd_bus_add_object_vtable(bus, &slot, "/example/example/test",
                                 "example.example.test", example_vtable,
                                 &example);
    if (r < 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Issue while attaching vtable %s\n", strerror(-r));
    r = sd_bus_request_name(bus, "example.example.test", 0);
    if (r < 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't retrieve interface name, error code %s\n",
                strerror(-r));
    printf("Dbus interface and property correctly configured\n");
    while (1) {
        r = sd_bus_process(bus, NULL);
        if (r < 0)
            fprintf(stderr, "Process exited promptly, %s\n", strerror(-r));
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Source code for the reader.c

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <systemd/sd-bus.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct Example {
    int a;
    const char *b;
    bool c;
} Example;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    sd_bus *bus;
    sd_bus_error error = SD_BUS_ERROR_NULL;
    sd_bus_message *message = NULL;
    sd_bus_message *reply = NULL;
    Example example = {0};
    int r = sd_bus_open(&bus);
    if (r < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Issue connecting to system bus, error %s\n",
                strerror(-r));
        exit(-1);
    }
    for (;;) {
        r = sd_bus_get_property(bus, "example.example.test",
                                "/example/example/test", "example.example.test",
                                "Example_property", &error, &message, "ay");
        if (r < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Issue receiving property %s\n", strerror(-r));
            continue;
        }
        printf("This is print\n");
        r = sd_bus_message_read(message, "ay", &example, sizeof(Example));
        if (r < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Issue with read message %s\n",
                    strerror(-r));
            continue;
        }
        printf("Does not reach here\n");
        if (sizeof(example) != sizeof(Example)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Bad\n");
            continue;
        }
        printf("Received %d, %s, %d\n", example.a, example.b, example.c);
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with ```` gcc -g -o sender/reader.out sender/reader.c ```pkg-config --libs libststemd``` -Wall -pedantic ````

I tried multiple implementations derived from the idea of sending the entirety of the struct as a dbus property.

Including different `static int example_get_property` function implementations, such as:

```c
static int example_get_property(sd_bus *bus, const char *path,
                                const char *interface, const char *property,
                                sd_bus_message *reply, void *userdata,
                                sd_bus_error *error) {
    Example *ex = (Example *)userdata;
    sd_bus_message_append_array(reply, 'y', ex, sizeof(Example));
    return 1;
}

static int example_get_property(sd_bus *bus, const char *path,
                                const char *interface, const char *property,
                                sd_bus_message *reply, void *userdata,
                                sd_bus_error *error) {
    Example *ex = (Example *)userdata;
    sd_bus_message_append(reply, "i", ex->a);
    sd_bus_message_append(reply, "s", ex->b);
    sd_bus_message_append(reply, "b", ex->c);
    return 1;
}

static int example_get_property(sd_bus *bus, const char *path,
                                const char *interface, const char *property,
                                sd_bus_message *reply, void *userdata,
                                sd_bus_error *error) {
    Example *ex = (Example *)userdata;
    uint8_t buf[sizeof(Example)];
    memcpy(buf, ex, sizeof(Example));
    sd_bus_message_append_array(reply, 'y', buf, sizeof(Example));
    return 1;
}
```

But all of them produced the segmentation fault in the line mentioned.

Comment: lol, I do love a good passive-aggressive comment when I see one

Comment: I already reached a point in which chatGPT was repeating solutions I already tested, and since I was stuck in a loop I decided to try with the stackoverflow community.

Comment: `Example *ex = (Example *)userdata;` Why do you think that is valid? Is the buffer properly aligned? `I always ended up with a segmentation fault` What is the stacktrace in your debugger when that happens? Which line of code exactly triggers the fault? Does the segmentation fault happens in reader or writer?

Comment: The problem with ChatGPT is it doesn't really know how to write software. But it's very good at assembling and regurgitating stuff that looks like software.

Comment: Regarding the `example_get_property` I relied on the chatGPT suggestion to implement it that way, I have my doubts aswell regarding if it makes sense or not.
The line that triggers the segmentation fault is the `sd_bus_message_read() function call` in the reader.c file.

Comment: @paddy I totally agree with you on that one haha

Comment: There is no C++ in sight here, is there a reason to mention it? There is no such thing as "C/C++", there is C, there is C++. Your code seems to be in C. Prefer to use `$(...)` over backticks for comand substitution in shell.

Comment: @KamilCuk you are right, for this particular example I only provided a C sample, but I wanted to check if I can achieve what I asked in the question because I'm working on a project in which the equivalent to my sender will be written in C++, and the reader will be written in C. Thanks for the suggestion nonetheless, should I modify the question? I tried to make it as simple as possible

Comment: Also `sender.c:35:21: error: unused variable ‘message’ [-Werror=unused-variable]
   35 |     sd_bus_message *message = NULL;
      |                     ^~~~~~~
sender.c:33:18: error: unused variable ‘error’ [-Werror=unused-variable]
   33 |     sd_bus_error error = SD_BUS_ERROR_NULL;`, I do not think you tested `-Werror` ;)

Comment: `AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==255801==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000018 (pc 0x7f00253bbe78 bp 0x000000000017 sp 0x7ffd62abaff0 T0)
==255801==The signal is caused by a WRITE memory access.
==255801==Hint: address points to the zero page.
    #0 0x7f00253bbe78 in sd_bus_message_read_basic (/usr/lib/libsystemd.so.0+0x2ce78)
` ... `#3 0x55bdd7d696e3 in main /home/kamil/tmp/reader.c:35` Use address sanitizer and valgrind to detect errors.

Comment: @KamilCuk I removed the -Werror flag from the compilation instructions, previously I was using those variables but I forgot about them. Regarding the `sd_bus_message *message = NULL;` the function `sd_bus_get_property` gets a pointer to the message as an input and fills it with the corresponding data so your suggestion would not apply here I think.

Comment: `sd_bus_message_read(message, "ay", &example, sizeof(Example));` This is invalid. Firstly, `a` the type of the first argument is __int__ of the length. Then it follows __n__ arguments of `uint8_t*` type to store the output. I'm reading `man sd_bus_message_read`. Also, are you _aware_ that you are sending the `const char *b;` pointer __value__, not the pointed to content?

Comment: @paddy It's not just software — the problem with ChatGPT is that it doesn't know *anything*.   It's very good at assembling and regurgitating stuff that looks like English sentences, but if they contain any actual facts or insight, it's only by accident.  ChatGPT has aptly been described as a "[super-autocomplete](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/03/08/opinion/noam-chomsky-chatgpt-ai.html)".

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm sorry, I'm not following you regarding the `const char *c` suggestion, when you create a string "s" signature property in dbus you associate it to a either a `char * or const char *` attribute of a struct. I have worked with strings before this way and could read the properties fine in the readers implementation.
Plus once the get property is called and the pointer address is stored in a dbus message, you can trigger a message read and parse the result to a local `char * or const char *` variable which will contain the address, and use it or dereference it.

Comment: `use it or dereference it` You can't dereference an address from a different program. These are two programs. One sends an address to the other. The other can't derefernce it. It's one of fundamental security mechanisms in an OS. You can't read other processes memory. `when you create a string "s" signature property in dbus` when you do, then you send the string contents. The presented code does not do that.

Comment: @KamilCuk I think that you don't need to access the original memory address for this, you access the memory address of the preallocated string which is contained in the dbus message. And parse it to your local program, then in your local program it acts as any other array of chars would

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> sd_bus_message_read(message, "ay", &example, sizeof(Example));
> ```

Is invalid, and immidately triggers address sanitizer. First argument for `a` should be an **int** with the size of the array. Then there should be **n** arguments (not one argument, **n** arguments) of type `uint8_t*` to store the output.

Instead, use `sd_bus_message_read_array` as you sent an array, not n messages of type `uint8_t`.

Note that `const char *b` - you are sending *the value* of the pointer, not the content of the pointed to data.

The following code:

sender.c:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <systemd/sd-bus.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct Example {
    int a;
    const char *b;
    bool c;
} Example;

// I think this function creates an array out of the data of the struct and appends it to the
// sd_bus_message, not quite sure
static int example_get_property(sd_bus *bus, const char *path,
                                const char *interface, const char *property,
                                sd_bus_message *reply, void *userdata,
                                sd_bus_error *error) {
    Example *ex = (Example *)userdata;
        printf("sending %d %p %d\n", ex->a, (void*)ex->b, ex->c);
    sd_bus_message_append_array(reply, 'y', ex, sizeof(Example));
    return 1;
}

static const sd_bus_vtable example_vtable[] = {
    SD_BUS_VTABLE_START(0),
    SD_BUS_PROPERTY("Example_property", "ay", example_get_property, 0,
                    SD_BUS_VTABLE_PROPERTY_EMITS_CHANGE),
    SD_BUS_VTABLE_END};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    sd_bus_slot *slot = NULL;
    sd_bus_error error = SD_BUS_ERROR_NULL;
    sd_bus *bus = NULL;
    sd_bus_message *message = NULL;
    Example example = {.a = 69, .b = "random test", .c = false};
    int r = sd_bus_open(&bus);
    if (r < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open system bus, error code %s\n",
                strerror(-r));
        printf("Exiting program\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    r = sd_bus_add_object_vtable(bus, &slot, "/example/example/test",
                                 "example.example.test", example_vtable,
                                 &example);
    if (r < 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Issue while attaching vtable %s\n", strerror(-r));
    r = sd_bus_request_name(bus, "example.example.test", 0);
    if (r < 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't retrieve interface name, error code %s\n",
                strerror(-r));
    printf("Dbus interface and property correctly configured\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
        r = sd_bus_process(bus, NULL);
        if (r < 0)
            fprintf(stderr, "Process exited promptly, %s\n", strerror(-r));
        sleep(1);
    }
        sd_bus_close(bus);
    return 0;
}
```

reader.c:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <systemd/sd-bus.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct Example {
    int a;
    const char *b;
    bool c;
} Example;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    sd_bus *bus;
    sd_bus_error error = SD_BUS_ERROR_NULL;
    sd_bus_message *message = NULL;
    sd_bus_message *reply = NULL;
    int r = sd_bus_open(&bus);
    if (r < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Issue connecting to system bus, error %s\n",
                strerror(-r));
        exit(-1);
    }
        r = sd_bus_get_property(bus, "example.example.test",
                                                        "/example/example/test", "example.example.test",
                                                        "Example_property", &error, &message, "ay");
        if (r < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Issue receiving property %s\n", strerror(-r));
                exit(-1);
        }
        printf("This is print\n");
        const void *pointer = 0;
        size_t size = 0;
        r = sd_bus_message_read_array(message, 'y', &pointer, &size);
        if (r < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Issue with read message %s\n",
                                strerror(-r));
                exit(-1);
        }
        union {
                char buffer[sizeof(Example)];
                Example example;
        } u;
        assert(size == sizeof(Example));
        memcpy(u.buffer, pointer, size);
        printf("Does not reach here\n");
        printf("Received %d, %p, %d\n", u.example.a, (void*)u.example.b, u.example.c);
        sd_bus_close(bus);
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
CC = gcc -g `pkg-config --libs libsystemd` -fsanitize=undefined,address
all:
        $(CC) -o sender.out sender.c
        $(CC) -o reader.out reader.c
        timeout -v 10 ./sender.out & sleep 1 && ./reader.out ; wait
```

Correctly receives the message and prints a lot about malloc leaks:

```
$ make
gcc -g `pkg-config --libs libsystemd` -fsanitize=undefined,address -o sender.out sender.c
gcc -g `pkg-config --libs libsystemd` -fsanitize=undefined,address -o reader.out reader.c
Dbus interface and property correctly configured
sending 69 0x56099f05f180 0
This is print
Does not reach here
Received 69, 0x56099f05f180, 0
```

Note that using an `union` to alias buffer like that is valid in C and completely invalid in C++.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, regarding this part: `Note that const char *b - you are sending the value of the pointer, not the content of the pointed to data.` I can provide you an example, of a `const char *string` being read from a reader using dbus the exact same way as I did in the source code provided, the only difference being that for this other example I don't provide a full structure as a property, only the attributes individually.
And I can access the data stored in the string itself not the memory address.